# value of this when used with function.call giving unexpected output

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript i was trying to understand the concept of this when used with apply/call but i am stuck in this code.

```
foo = function(){
  console.log(this)
}
foo.call("random")
```

the output is giving a string object as expected but why the string is shown as an array of string.

```
String { 0="r", 1="a", 2="n", 3="d", 4="o", 5="m" }
```

what i was expecting was.

```
String{ }
```

which is the case with numbers

```
foo.call(121)
```

where output is

```
Number{ }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the output is giving a string object as expected

only because you're using sloppy mode. In strict mode, it would be a primitive string value.

> but why the string is shown as an array of string.

Because [`String` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) are array-like, having a `.length` and single-character-strings on their indices. How your console displays that is however implementation dependent:

```
// Chrome
String {0: "r", 1: "a", 2: "n", 3: "d", 4: "o", 5: "m", length: 6}
// Firefox
String { 0="r", 1="a", 2="n", more...}
// Opera
[+] String
// IE
▷ [object String]{0: "r", 1: "a", 2: "n", 3: "d", 4: "o", 5: "m", length: 6}
```